If S is compact, then a separating class is a convergence determining class
This exact question (exercise 5.2 in Ch.1 of Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures) was asked a few years ago, but I think there may be an error in the accepted answer. A commenter pointed it out, but it was never addressed. This is my thinking:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a separating class. We want to show that if for a sequence of probability measures $\{P_n\}$, there exists a probability measure $P$ with $P_nA\to PA$ for all $A$, a $P$ continuity set of $\mathcal{A}$, then in fact $P_n\Rightarrow P$.
Now $S$ is compact and $P_nS=1$ for all $n$, and so by Prohorov's Theorem, $\{P_n\}$ is relatively compact. Let $\{P_{n_i}\}$ be a subsequence. Then there exists a probability measure $Q$ and a further subsequence $\{P_{n_{i(m)}}\}$ such that $P_{n_{i(m)}}\Rightarrow Q$. Then if $A$ is a $Q$-continuity set of $S$, $P_{n_{i(m)}}A\to QA$. Now, suppose there exists a probability measure $P$ with $P_nB\to PB$ for $B$, a $P$-continuity set of $\mathcal{A}$. Thus if $C$ is both a $Q$-continuity set of $S$ and a $P$-continuity set of $\mathcal{A}$, $PC=QC$. We would like to conclude $P=Q$, but for that to occur, we need $P$ and $Q$ to coincide on all of $\mathcal{A}$. If we had this, then every subsequence would contain a further subsequence converging weakly to $P$, which shows $P_n\Rightarrow P$.

For reference, for Billingsley a separating class is a set $\mathcal{A}\subset S$ such that if $PA=QA$ for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$, then $P=Q$. A convergence determining (or "limit determining") class is a set $\mathcal{A}\subset S$ such that if $P_nA\to PA$ for all $A$, a $P$-continuity set of $\mathcal{A}$, then $P_n\Rightarrow P$.
